# Whats the advantage of doing optional binding over sequential binding in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

In the short tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef), in step 5 a delegate is assigned:

```
if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
   let classBVC = nav.topViewController as? ClassBVC {
       // 'self' is ClassAVC which has been delegated.
       classBVC.delegate = self
   }
```

I find it hard to follow this statements, so is it a big disadvantage to just write:

```
let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
let classBVC = nav?.topViewController as? ClassBVC
classBVC!.delegate = self
```

Comment: the first noticable disadvantadge is that it'll crash if it can't cast it. Sure you can say that you know for a fact that it won't crash because the topViewController is always ClassBVC, but that assumption might not always be true (whether it be now or in the future). It's always good to play it safe and safely unwrap when appropriate. Plus if you're going to not safely unwrap it you might as well cast it straight with `as!` instead of `as?`

Comment: So this is to avoid crashing incase the topViewController changed type? What are situations where it would change type? A new interface builder scene? I somehow feel like "A scene is a class".

Comment: If you say `classBVC?.delegate` instead of `classBVC!.delegate`, then your code is completely fine and will not crash (but won't set the delegate if `classBVC` is nil, obviously).

Comment: What are reasons to assume it could be optional in the first place?

Comment: @TMOTTM `classBVC` will be optional no matter what because of the optional chaining and the use of `as?`.

Comment: Honestly, since this is all specific to your particular UI, there probably *aren't* any reasons to assume it'll be `nil`, assuming your xib/storyboard is set up with the segue destination and top view controller being the classes described here. So you probably *could* get away with using `as!`, although I'd recommend looking at Dávid's solution involving `guard let`, which I like to use for these situations, since it lets you bail out with a nice error message explaining the problem rather than just crashing. `as!` is fine too for these situations, though.

Comment: Keep in mind that if it is truly a bug in your app if either of the casts would fail, then it is perfectly fine to replace `as?` with `as!`. This eliminates the need for the optional chaining. Do this if there is no question that the casts should work and would only fail because you setup your storyboard incorrectly and you want the app to crash now so you can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as sequential binding. What you do in the second statement is called optional chaining with optional casting, which would be safe if not for the force unwrapping in your last line.

The force unwrapping here makes your second solution unsafe. If any of the previous optional operations resulted in a `nil` value, a runtime exception will occur.

```
classBVC!.delegate = self
```

If you need to unwrap an optional value, optional binding is one of the best options for doing so. You can make the boilerplate code of optional unwrapping minimal by reducing the number of `if let` statement. In some scenarios, using `guard let` instead of `if let` can also result in clearer code, since you won't have to nest the blocks inside each other.

Using optional binding, you will never see an

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

runtime exception, which you will likely see quite often if you do force unwrapping on optionals which might actually have a `nil` value.

```
guard let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let classBVC = nav.topViewController as? ClassBVC else { return }
classBVC.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you are stating that `classBVC` is absolutely a `ClassBVC` object. If you wrap it in the `if let` statement, if one fails it will not crash unwrapping a nil value.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your second pattern if successful operation of your app requires `ClassBVC` be the top view controller of the navigation controller that is `destination`. In fact, I actually prefer your second pattern, because with former pattern (the optional casting/unwrapping), if any of those casts failed, the code would silently progress without letting you know that a serious problem had arisen. And you'd be struggling to figure out why your delegate methods weren't called.

The only minor tweak I might suggest would be that if this is really the requirement, I'd remove optional casting/chaining altogether. There's no point in having two lines of optional casting/chaining followed by a forced unwrapping that will fail if either of the two previous lines of optional casting/chaining failed. I'd make it explicit in the code:

```
let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
let classBVC = nav.topViewController as! ClassBVC
classBVC.delegate = self
```

This way, when reading your code, you don't have to get to the third line to determine that the previous two casts weren't really optional, but rather were essential. This revision makes that clear.

---

If you feel compelled to `guard` against the situation where one of these casts might fail, I'd suggest making sure you inform the developer if these essential (assuming they are truly required) casts failed:

```
guard let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let classBVC = nav.topViewController as? ClassBVC else {
    fatalError("destination should be nav controller who's top view controller is a ClassBVC")
}

classBVC.delegate = self
```

I don't personally think this is much better than the above pattern (sure, the error is more explicit, but I don't think the code is any more readable and the result, crashing if the cast failed, is the same). But if you want a more informative error message, that's one way to tackle that.